# Istanbul coverage with mocha test cases only showing coverage report for spec files (test files)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

Istanbul coverage report only shows coverage report for the spec files i.e the test files and not the original router and controllers files.

It displays 100% coverage for spec files and 0% for the router files.

The command i am using is npm test:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=development istanbul cover --include-all-sources --root ./server ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive './server/**/**/**/*-spec.js'"
```

Below is the screenshot of the coverage report html file by istanbul
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work for me, maybe you can pick some of my configs and apply them to your environment

1. My current packages version

   ```
   "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
   "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
   "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.0.1",
   "chai": "^4.1.2",
   "mocha": "^5.2.0",
   "nyc": "^13.0.1"
   ```
2. Update/Create your `.babelrc` adding the pluging for istanbul

   { 
       "plugins": ["istanbul"]
   }
3. Create a config file for istanbul: `.nycrc` and paste this configuration

   {  "require": ["@babel/register"],
       "exclude": ["**/*.{test,spec}.js"],
       "all": true,
       "instrument": false    }

You can check for more options in the official [nyc repository](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc)

4. Then run the tests

`./node_modules/.bin/nyc mocha **/*.{test,spec}.js`

*or*

`npx nyc mocha **/*.{test,spec}.js`